# Retornar o Id da tabela 1 e inserir na tabela 2 no mesmo código

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

Fala galera, seguinte, to com 2 tabelas (Grupo1 e Grupo2), ai tenho um form que tem vários campos que serão inseridos ao mesmo tempo nessas 2 tabelas. Mas preciso inserir na tabela Grupo2 o Id da tabela Grupo1 que acabou de ser gerado nesse Save. Vi várias coisas assim usando o OUTPUT mas não sei o que fazer depois de recuperar o valor assim. O que eu preciso seria mais ou menos isso

```
insert into Grupo1
values (nome, idade, telefone)
output inserted.Grupo1Id // aqui é o valor que quero
insert into grupo2
values (<inserted.Grupo1Id>)
```

Ou seja, eu sei recuperar o valor mas não sei atribuí-lo à cláusula do segundo Insert. Ai ficaria assim na tabela

- Grupo1: Grupo1Id, nome, idade, telefone
- Grupo2: nome, Grupo1IdIgualAoDaLinhaDeCima

É uma dúvida bem simples mas não acho essa "parte final" pra solucionar o problema, obrigado a todos.

Answer (score 2):

Melhor que usar `@@IDENTITY` é usar [`SCOPE_IDENTITY()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-BR/library/ms190315.aspx), que retorna o último valor assinalado em uma coluna tipo `IDENTITY` *feita no escopo atual*, isto é, que foi efetivamente inserida pelo código que você está rodando. Isto é importante porque, se amanhã alguém põe um `AFTER INSERT TRIGGER` na tabela `Grupo1` que insere numa tabela de *log* que **tem uma coluna tipo `IDENTITY`,** isso vai fazer com que a `@@IDENTITY` retorne o valor da coluna da *tabela de log*, não da `Grupo1`.

Então o código ficaria assim:

```
insert into Grupo1
values (nome, idade, telefone);
insert into Grupo2
values (SCOPE_IDENTITY());
```

Answer (score 0):

Olá, Junior

existem algumas maneiras que eu faria. Veja se algumas dessas lhe ajuda:

1. Utilizar o ***@@IDENTITY***: o @@IDENTITY retorna o último ID inserido no banco, independente da tabela. Se você tem certeza que o último registro inserido foi da tabela Grupo1, então o valor de @@IDENTITY é o Grupo1ID. Referência: https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms187342(v=sql.120).aspx
2. Utilizar uma consulta para retornar o último registro inserido na tabela Grupo1. Essa consulta é bem simples, e pode ser assim:

   SELECT MAX(Grupo1ID) FROM Grupo1

Com essas duas opções, você possuirá o ID do Grupo1 a ser inserido no INSERT do Grupo2.

Espero ter ajudado,

Vinicius

Comment: Vou tentar ao chegar em casa, mas e como faço pra usar esse valor pra inserir em outra tabela? Sugestões?

Answer (score 0):

Você pode fazer da seguinte forma

```
declare @Grupo1 table
(
    Grupo1Id int  IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    nome varchar(100),
    idade int, 
    telefone varchar(15)
)

declare @Grupo2 table
(
    Grupo2Id int  IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    Grupo1Id int
)

declare @Grupo1Id int 
insert into @Grupo1 values ('nome', 2, '222222')

set @Grupo1Id = @@IDENTITY -- aqui é o valor que quero

insert into @Grupo2
values (@Grupo1Id)
```